# Create Vertical SCNPlane parallel to camera

Tags: ios, swift3, arkit

i want to create an SCNPlane when user taps on screen right in front of the camera, i can create the plane but its not parallel to camera

```
    guard let sceneView = sender.view as? ARSCNView else {return}
    guard let currentFrame = sceneView.session.currentFrame else {return}
    let camera = currentFrame.camera
    let transform = camera.transform
    var translationMatrix = matrix_identity_float4x4
    translationMatrix.columns.3.z = -0.1
    var modifiedMatrix = simd_mul(transform, translationMatrix)
    let plane = SCNNode(geometry: SCNPlane(width: 0.42, height: 0.63))
    plane.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.yellow
    plane.simdTransform = modifiedMatrix
    self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphere)
```

how do i orient the plane parallel to camera??
thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rotate your plane

```
    guard let sceneView = sender.view as? ARSCNView else {return}
    guard let currentFrame = sceneView.session.currentFrame else {return}
    let camera = currentFrame.camera
    let transform = SCNMatrix4(camera.transform)
    let translationMatrix = SCNMatrix4Rotate(
        SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 0, -0.1),
        Float.pi / 2,
        1, 0, 0)
    let modifiedMatrix = SCNMatrix4Mult(transform, translationMatrix)
    let plane = SCNNode(geometry: SCNPlane(width: 0.42, height: 0.63))
    plane.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.yellow
    plane.transform = modifiedMatrix
    self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(plane)
```

Comment: it doesnt rotate towards the camera, i think it will depend on the camera which axis is used to rotate

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have AR enabled device with me today, so I can't be sure.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't check code myself today. I'm not quite understand what "parallel to camera" means to you. If you want to place plane in from of your screen, your code seems ok. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/602/ (22:20) Please mind that your placing 42x63 cm rectangle, it is definitely bigger then iPhone. Don't forget to initialise AR kit and receive proper session tracking state prior to adding your object.

Comment: you are 100% correct my code was doing what i wanted to do, i was just pointing the camera at a white blank wall i think arkit gets confused when there are no markers in screen

Answer (score 1):

Rotating using

```
node.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
```

worked great for me. At first I had a plane node which was parallel to the camera, but now it lays on the ground.